# Rather use the Jenkins Agent images from quay.io or from registry.redhat.io?

Tags: jenkins, openshift

For updating my Jenkins Agents running in OpenShift, I consider using the Jenkins Agent image available at `quay.io/openshift/origin-jenkins-agent-base:4.7`. However, there is another one available at `registry.redhat.io/openshift4/ose-jenkins-agent-base:v4.7`.

Are there any substantial differences between these images?

If my research is correct (`docker inspect ...`), the one on *registry.redhat.io* is based on a Git commit from November 2021 (https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/commit/1524f28a04cf6882177968c95b11a8018596e05c), while the one on *quay.io* is based on a Git commit from February 2 2022 (https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/commit/1383028376d7619e1930d0f2a88aa00cce770226). And of course, the one at *quay.io* is available without any authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably makes sense to use the quay images, if you want to stick to publicly available images.

```
Starting with v4.0, the images are only available on quay.io for public community support. Their pull specs are:
```

Please note, that this strongly depends if you're using OpenShift v3 (which is EOL) or OpenShift v4
https://github.com/openshift/jenkins#installation-openshift-v4

Comment: I'm using the agent image from quay.io for a year now, and everything works well so far.